# Frame around some figures but not all

Tags: floats

I used this:
`\floatstyle{boxed}` and `\restylefloat{figure}` to get a frame around all figures. Is there a way to switch the frame for specific figures off, but still using this two instructions in the preamble? MWE below.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{boxed}
\restylefloat{figure}

\begin{document}

%Figure with a box around
\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics{example}
\end{figure}

%Figure without a box around?

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Float styles can be set in a `group`, i.e.

```
{%
\floatstyle{plain}
\restylefloat 
\begin{figure}
 ...
\caption{foo}
\end{figure}
}
```

This settings lasts only for all figures that are inside the `{....}`, outside the global setting holds.

To switch off the framed style, just say `\floatstyle{plain}`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{boxed}
\restylefloat{figure}

\begin{document}

%Figure with a box around
\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics{example}
\end{figure}

{%
\floatstyle{plain}
\restylefloat{figure}
\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics{example}
\end{figure}
}

\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics{example}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]